# Scraping restaurants long/lat data using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, latitude-longitude, rvest, tripadvisor

I'm currently trying to scrape lat/long data from tripadvisor. 
i can see the longitude and latitude in the source code of the page but i can't scrape it.
this is my code:

```
        library(rvest) 
    WS <- "https://www.tripadvisor.fr/Restaurant_Review-g187147-d10514254-Reviews-Les_Apotres_de_Pigalle-Paris_Ile_de_France.html"

link <- read_html(WS)

lat <- link %>%  html_node(".mapContainer ") %>% html_attr("data-lat")
```

when i run this code i have a "NA".

any help would be awesome ! thanks

Comment: You used the variable `WS` to save the url string and then used the variable  `site`

Comment: This is a violation of their [T&C](https://tripadvisor.mediaroom.com/FR-terms-of-use) and is subject to at least civil penalties and — in some jurisdictions — criminal penalties. Anyone who aids may have legal action taken against them and may have their IP address banned from using Trip Advisor.

Comment: My usecase is getting coordinates for personal use in GPS, so the alarmist message should not be perceived as an overly critical one :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to scrape via xpath

For latitude

```
"substring-after(substring-before(substring-before(substring-after(normalize-space(//script[contains(.,'lat: ')]), '= {'), ', zoom:'), ','), 'lat: ')"
```

For longtitude

```
"substring-after(substring-before(substring-after(normalize-space(//script[contains(.,'lat: ')]), '= {'), ', zoom:'), ' lng: ')"
```